# using hibernate and ibatis together in an application is good?

Tags: hibernate, ibatis

May i use hibernate for dynamic data retrieval and ibatis for regular data retrieval together in an application? Is it good to mix both technologies?

planning to use ibatis 2.3.0 with hibernate 4.0.1

Comment: what is dynamic data retrieval and regualr data retrieval?.

Comment: dynamic is based on user input.regular retrieval repeating retrieval of same set of data.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED
both are ORM frameworks

and if you think one is better for some use case and other is better in another case , then go ahead and have have both dependencies in your project. Inject the dependency using Spring or any other IoC framework.

In this case both will create their on connection pool, you have to take care of that.

Comment: Ibatis is not JPA implementation, it's just a layer between java objects and JDBC

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that whether it is possible then I have worked on an application where the main Persistence provider was Hibernate, however one component of it ( an open source product) was internally using IBatis. So it is quite possible. However it would be difficult to maintain two ORM's which are conceptually different and common only in fact that they eventually map JDBC resultset to application objects. If you want more control on SQL generated use IBatis.
Hibernate has its own use cases but the learning curve is steep. In either case you must have solid conceptual knowledge of database and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use iBatis: 
- If you want to create and maintain your own SQL queries, and thus keep control over the SQL that is executed. 
- If your environment is based on the relational data model. 
- If you need to work with a pre existing complex schema

Use Hibernate: 
- If your environment is based on the object and you want to generate the SQL model automatically.

Both solutions work well in their specific areas. For you to find the opportunity to use both together. If you really have a specific case where one is better you have the possibility to use the both technology.

[iBATIS vs Hibernate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ibatis/ibatis_vs_hibernate.htm)

[Which is right for you?](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077875/open-source-tools/ibatis--hibernate--and-jpa--which-is-right-for-you-.html)